# Nested for each loops in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, nested-loops

I have two arrays fetch from web servers, both only contains same numbers of dictionaries. i want to parse every dictionary in two nested for each loops, so used following code:

```
for (NSDictionary *subscription in feedsArray)
{
    for (NSDictionary *unreadCount in unreadCountsArray)
    {
        [RDInsertObjects insertFeedsWithSubscription:subscription
                         unreadCount:unreadCount];
    }
}
```

But the results returned isn't me wanted, the inner for loop seemed executed over many times, anyone can tell me how exactly do right things to make this code make sense?

Comment: It's hard to give a solution without knowing exactly want you want to do with those dictionaries. Please, try to give more information, like the implementation of the method `insertFeedsWithSubscription:unreadCount:` or the content of the dictionaries

Comment: have you tried replacing [RDInsertObjects insertFeedsWithSubscription:subscription
                         unreadCount:unreadCount] with simply an NSLog statement of both feedsArray and unreadCountsArray? the above should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you do it, for each single iteration of the first loop the second loop iterates completely.

I think it won't work with a for-in loop. But you said the number of items in the two arrays is the same - so you can easily do:

```
for (i=0; i< feedsArray.count; i++) {
  NSDictionary subscription = feedsArray[i];
  NSDictionary unreadCount = unreadCountsArray[i];

  [RDInsertObjects insertFeedsWithSubscription: subscription unreadCount: unreadCount];
}
```

This will only work, if the number of items in the array are always ever the same - if sometime they aren't, you need a modification to prevent an out-of-bounds error or it will crash!

Comment: Wow, big thanks! Well resolved! BTW, is it enough efficiency to iterate arrays using this way? Which way is more efficiency between 'for in' and 'for condition loop'?

Comment: "for in' is the most efficient way of iterating. Generally, 'for in' is the fastest way of enumerating (as far as i know).

Comment: But I think the advantage of for-in over for-condition (if any, would have to check) is not noticible in that practical use-case of checking some maybe thousands (or likely less) dictionaries. Don't optimise code prematurely or did you notice a performance issue?

Comment: Did a quick search and @Rafal is right, fast enumeration is faster because of some optimisations (it's not just a for loop in disguise). However, as said before, the performance drop should not be an issue here.